# Runtime-specific imported dll in dotnet tool

Tags: dllimport, dotnet-tool

I'm trying to publish a [dotnet tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create) that depends on a library that uses a [dll import attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=net-8.0).

When I build the project & run it locally (without packaging it into a nupkg and then installing the tool), it works fine and the dll that's imported by the library appears in the directory `MyProject\bin\x64\Release\net6.0\x64` and (presumably a slightly different version) in `MyProject\bin\x64\Release\net6.0\x86`. Running it works.

When I instead follow the following steps:

1. `dotnet pack MyProject.csproj -c Release -o myOutputDirectory`
2. `dotnet tool install MyProject --tool-path myInstallPath` (install from the generated nupkg)

When I investigate the location of the mentioned DLLs, it seems to be the same as before. However, now when I invoke the tool (via `./myInstallPath/MyProject.exe`) I get:

> Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'MyImportedDll.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

Curious if anyone has insights on why there's a difference between how it behaves when run as an installed tool vs. just directly, and how to circumvent this issue?